# Do I need to create models for the request and response for every http request in iOS project?

Tags: ios, swift

1. If I create models for request and response parameters for every http request in iOS project, it is easier for me to deal with models rather than dictionaries.

However, it will create too many models.

Is this a good approach or not?

2. And during the development, I found if there is only one model, for example, in an online shopping system, I only have one store model. But I use it in store module, cart model and order model. Actually in each module, the different attributes of the store model has been used. So this giant model always has some extra attributes for usage in each module.

Is this a good approach to manage the models in iOS projects? Or should I create CartStore model, OrderStore model?

Comment: To me, I will create models for different flows/modules to adapt Single Responsibility Principle. From your shoes, the Store model should only contain the attributes of the store, if Cart or Order module need any further attributes then you should create another model.

Comment: Yep. I do agree with Single Responsibility Principle. But this means I need to create quite a lot of models as the app grows?

Comment: Sure, you will; each model will be in charge of a single logic and of course you need to manage those models and pls notice that having a lot of models doesnt mean your app performance or build performance will be slow.

Comment: I agree it won't impact the performance. And it makes the codes are more clear(responsibility). Yeah, a lot of files. Maybe a little bit overwhelming for the new guys and longer compiling time. But it makes the code easier to maintain. I guess. Am I right?

Comment: Sure, to me, it's easier to maintain, logic is not to heavy for each model class; you will see this advantage once you business logic grows up

Comment: Sure, @Michael. Thanks

Comment: Gave you an upvote already. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks man! Have a nice day there. @jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, you should create models for different flows/modules to adapt Single Responsibility Principle.

From your shoes, the Store model should only contain the attributes of the store, if Cart or Order module need any further attributes then you should create another model.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The model approach will save a ton of your time when come back to fix or add on a new feature. Sure, They will take quite time but today Apple has already provide code `codable/decodable` protocol which will help you to handle parsing between JSON and Object Model. Also writing a unit test or even integration test it will be much easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Base on which data response of request, if have the same data structure should only create 1.

Ex: **api get all stores** and **api get store with condition** (distance, rating, ...) return storeModel, then we just using only 1 storeModel. And we have **api get store detail** (this api return more info than api get list stores above) just add more property in storeModel and using it again. So that with 3 apis, we only using **storeModel**

2. With your example, I think should create StoreModel, CartModel and OrderModel inherits from BaseModel. In this BaseModel, we'll have the all property which StoreModel, CartModel and OrderModel have, and in each children model, we will have only specific property.

Hope this help!